# subprocess.check_call([PYTHON_PATH, try_str[i]]) The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a path 'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load' where I store 9 (nine) folders.

Each of this folders contains a main.py among other things.

I've written a script and placed it on the dir: 'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load', so that it will access the main.py contained in every folder.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess 
import os  

PYTHON_PATH = r'C:\Python34\python.exe' 
CURRENT_PATH = r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load'

try_str = [r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\1\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\2\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\3\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\4\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\5\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\6\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\7\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\8\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\9\main.py']   

for i in range(len(try_str)):   
   subprocess.check_call([PYTHON_PATH, try_str[i]])
```

This is the exception i get when executing it

```
D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load>python subprocesses_handler.py

D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\1\main.py True

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subprocesses_handler.py", line 33, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call([PYTHON_PATH, try_str[i]])
  File "C:\Users\torresl\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 \lib\subprocess.py", line 556, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\torresl\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\torresl\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\torresl\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

"Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" is german for "The system cannot find the file"

---

At this point i really don't know what's going on... First i made a list with the module os to get all the folders in the directory... and then i made the list try_str and copied and paste the path of every single folder to be sure that there were not incompatibilities of '\' and '\'...

Please give me a hand!

Thx.

Comment: Are you sure your python.exe is at `PYTHON_PATH = r'C:\Python34\python.exe' ` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you get an error like -

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Or its german version, it means the you specified a wrong executable. My guess is that the Python executable is not in the location you specified - `C:\Python34\python.exe` .

Anyway, you really do not need to manually put the value of path to `Python.exe` , you can instead use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the path to the Python executable with which the current program was run.

You can use this instead in your program. Example -

```
import subprocess 
import os  
import sys

CURRENT_PATH = r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load'

try_str = [r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\1\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\2\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\3\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\4\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\5\main.py',\
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\6\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\7\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\8\main.py',\ 
r'D:\Torres\Gas_Entrapment\new_calculations\command_script_load\Es_cteS_cte\w_load\9\main.py']   

for i in range(len(try_str)):   
   subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, try_str[i]])
```

Though in most cases, you really don't even need this, and you can simply use `'python'` , and let the os decide which python to use based on the `PATH` env variable.